# Authorization error while implementing google auhentication in django app

Tags: django, google-authentication

In my django project I have added google authentication API for user login and have deployed that project in heroku server[https://artgreeh.herokuapp.com]. I tried login through Google it worked with no issue in some machine but it's showing error in other machine. [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omoXv.jpg). In the google I have given redirect url-"https://artgreeh.herokuapp.com/accounts/google/login/callback/". If something is wrong with redirect url then it should not work in any device but it's working in some device.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced "https" with "http" in the redirect url and it worked.